# How to auto tweet via API in php using localhost?

Tags: php, twitter, localhost, echo, twitter-oauth

I am new to PHP. I have the following code and i seriously would like to have the result posted as a tweet via its API. Can anybody provide an example code how would i be able to achieve that result? I think the twitter API script should go after the submit button or so. Also when i created twitter application for this, they asked me for a url but how can i provide it? Since i am using xampp server to run PHP scripts on port number 9999. So would entering localhost:9999 in the url work? Please and thanks...

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<form action="abc.php" method="POST">
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="typehere"></textarea><br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="tweet this">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" class="button" value="Clear">
</from>

<?php
  error_reporting(0);
  $tweet = $_POST["typehere"];
  echo "The following tweet has been tweeted.";
  echo $tweet;   

?>


</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the API "twitter-php"

This is the official website with a tutorial
https://code.google.com/p/twitter-php/

You need more than "text message" : the username and the password

Answer (score 0):

Well using the Twitter API is a bit more complicated than that.

You can use Twitter's REST Api, who works like a charm. You'll need to authenticate the user before posting, and some other things.

The complete and easy documentation is there : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update